# NSSegmentedControl action not firing

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, selector, appkit

I am not using any Storyboards/NIBs, I'm creating all my UI programmatically.

Here's the main window controller:

```
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController, NSToolbarDelegate {

    var toolbar: NSToolbar!
    var segmentedControl: NSSegmentedControl!

    override func loadWindow() {
        self.window = NSWindow(contentRect: .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 640, height: 480)),
                               styleMask: NSWindow.StyleMask(rawValue: (NSWindow.StyleMask.closable.rawValue | NSWindow.StyleMask.titled.rawValue | NSWindow.StyleMask.miniaturizable.rawValue | NSWindow.StyleMask.resizable.rawValue)),
                               backing: .buffered, defer: true)
    }

    override init(window: NSWindow?) {
        super.init(window: window)
        loadWindow()

        self.window?.center()

        self.segmentedControl = NSSegmentedControl(labels: ["1", "2", "3"], trackingMode: NSSegmentedControl.SwitchTracking.selectOne, target: self, action: #selector(switchTabs))
        self.segmentedControl.setSelected(true, forSegment: 0)

        self.toolbar = NSToolbar(identifier: .init("MainToolbar"))
        self.toolbar.delegate = self
        self.toolbar.displayMode = .iconOnly
        self.window?.toolbar = self.toolbar

        self.window?.contentViewController = MainSplitViewController()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: - Selectors

    @objc func switchTabs(sender: Any) {
        let segmentedControl = sender as! NSSegmentedControl
        let tabVC = (self.window!.contentViewController as! MainSplitViewController!).tabViewController
        tabVC.tabView.selectTabViewItem(at: segmentedControl.selectedSegment)
    }

    // MARK: - NSToolbarDelegate

    func toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier] {
        return [
            NSToolbarItem.Identifier.init("Add"),
            NSToolbarItem.Identifier.flexibleSpace,
            NSToolbarItem.Identifier.init("NSSegmentedControl"),
            NSToolbarItem.Identifier.flexibleSpace,
            NSToolbarItem.Identifier.init("Search")
        ]
    }

    func toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier] {
        return [
            NSToolbarItem.Identifier.flexibleSpace,
            NSToolbarItem.Identifier.init("NSSegmentedControl"),
            NSToolbarItem.Identifier.init("Search"),
            NSToolbarItem.Identifier.init("Add")
        ]
    }

    func toolbar(_ toolbar: NSToolbar, itemForItemIdentifier itemIdentifier: NSToolbarItem.Identifier, willBeInsertedIntoToolbar flag: Bool) -> NSToolbarItem? {
        switch itemIdentifier {
        case NSToolbarItem.Identifier.flexibleSpace:
            return NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: itemIdentifier)
        case NSToolbarItem.Identifier.init("NSSegmentedControl"):
            let toolbarItem = NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: itemIdentifier)
            toolbarItem.view = self.segmentedControl
            return toolbarItem
        case NSToolbarItem.Identifier.init("Search"):
            let toolbarItem = NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: itemIdentifier)
            let searchField = NSSearchField(frame: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 64, height: 64 )))
            toolbarItem.view = searchField
            return toolbarItem
        case NSToolbarItem.Identifier.init("Add"):
            let toolbarItem = NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: itemIdentifier)
            let addButton = NSButton(title: "Add", target: self, action: nil)
            toolbarItem.view = addButton
            return toolbarItem
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

I have three `NSViewControllers` embedded in an `NSTabViewController` in my window. I want to be able to connect them to the selection of the `NSSegmentedControl` in my `NSToolbar`.

However, the `action` is never being fired. The `switchTabs` method is never being called. If I call the function directly, then it works! But nothing happens when I select a `NSSegmentedCell`.

What's going wrong here?

Am I doing the instantiation of the window correctly? Is my usage of `loadWindow` correct?

Comment: I'm an Obj-C guy—so this might be completely wrong—but the first thing that jumps out at me is the possible mismatch between `#selector(switchTabs)` (no parameters) and `func switchTabs(sender: Any)` (one parameter).

Comment: I thought that too. When I use `#selector(switchTabs)` and I print the action (like so `print(segmentedControl.action!)`, it yields: `switchTabsWithSender:`. When I use  `#selector(switchTabs(sender:))`, it yields: `switchTabsWithSenderWithSender:`. I don't know if that's the problem, because neither of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get this working in it's current set up, so I set the `target` and `action` to my `NSTabViewController` and a `selector` in that class.

Answer (score 1):

I've replaced your MainSplitViewController with a simply NSViewController subclass with its own nib (because there's only so much 'creating the interface in code' I'm willing to do), and it runs just fine - the toolbar gets created, the segments fire their action, selectedSegment reports the correct tag.

This makes your contentViewController and its associated view the most likely culprit: your toolbar code works just fine.

Comment: This is really confusing. If I reference the window's toolbar inside the `NSTabViewController` embedded in my `NSSplitViewController`, then I can reset the `target` and `action` to selector inside the `NSTabViewController` and it works just fine. I am concerned that implementing it that way would be poor design.

Comment: Given that NSTabViewController conforms to NSToolbarDelegate and your main purpose is tab switching, (NSTabView has a 'takeSelectedTabViewFromSender' method), I don't see much of a problem with that; depending on what your 'add' function is about. I'd wonder more about why you feel you need to create your interface in code, rather than using nibs or storyboards, and I'd look at things like let segmentedControl = sender as! NSSegmentedControl instead of simply declaring sender to be an NSSegmentedControl (don't force unwrap when you can avoid it.)

Comment: I just prefer doing everything in code. It feels like I have more control that way. It's my first Cocoa app, and I have a Cocoa Touch background. A lot of it is very different and nearly all documentation and tutorials are outdated. So I'm constantly worried about doing things wrong.

Comment: I hear ya on the outdated documentation. I'm putting a lot of stuff on www.extelligentcocoa.org, but it's hard to keep up even with that. (I'm still on 10.12 right now, for instance.) As for interface in code, I feel that I have far more control in storyboards because I can see easily how things are connected and how they look instead of needing to spend brain power figuring them out. There's a general guideline, I feel: if Apple strongly hints that they want you to adapt a technology, life becomes easier when you do.